# Character Table of the *finite Heisenberg Group* $H_2$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

My task is to compute the character table of the *finite Heisenberg Group* $H_2$:

$$
\left\lbrace\ a=[a_1,a_2;a_3]:=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & a_1 & a_3 \\
0 & 1 & a_2 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\left. \right|\quad a_1,a_2,a_3\in\mathbb{Z}_2\right\rbrace\
$$
with matrix multiplication (mod n) and

$$
\mathbb{Z}_2:=\left(\left\lbrace\ 0,1 \right\rbrace\text{,}\text{ addition (mod n), multiplication (mod n)}\right)
$$

I need the help of you brilliant minds!

Comment: Do you require $n = 2$?

Comment: Standard procedure: start by computing the $1$-dimensional characters (so, by computing the abelianization), then try finding nice subgroups to induce from.

Comment: Thanks! But I don't get it why I have to compute the abelianization in order to get the characters :-/

Comment: You don't *have* to, but it's a good standard way to start: Computing the abelianization is relatively easy, and from it, you can read off the linear (i.e. 1-dimensional) characters. Then, as Qiaochu Yuan suggested, you can try to induce these from suitable nice subgroups to find further characters. But of course there are other ways to proceed. How have you computed character tables so far in other examples?